# How would I have a class method that has two different names, but do the same thing?

Tags: javascript, class

I want this method to also be called if you do **unpause** instead of start.

```js
  start() {
    this.expected = Date.now() + this.tick;
    this.paused = false;
    this.update();
  }
```

How would I do this?

Comment: `unpause(){this.start();}`

Comment: Those (`expected` and `paused`) are not methods. They're values.

Comment: @Pointy by method, i was referring to start(), not the properties

Comment: ah OK, that wasn't clear. There's no way to do it as part of the `class` declaration other than what @MadyDaby suggested. You could do it after the class declaration on the prototype object, but that's a little messy.

Comment: @MadyDaby could you answer the question that way i can accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this function.

```
unpause(){
    this.start();
}
```